# How to make a function with summarize in R?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyverse, summarize

I don't know if that's the correct question but, I'm trying to make a function out of another function inside the summarize function:

```
library(tidyverse)

# one can use the summarize function to make several statistics

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(var = mean(mpg, na.rm = TRUE))

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(var = max(mpg, na.rm = TRUE))

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(var = min(mpg, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Question: How can I make a function (like the example below) to functionalize the examples above?

```
summarize_function <- function(statistic) {

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(var = statistic(mpg, na.rm = TRUE))

}
```

Comment: It appears that the function already does what you want - or do I miss something?

Comment: How are you calling `summarize_function` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the function name, e.g., `mean` or `max`, to `summarize_function`

```
> summarize_function(mean)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl   var
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4  26.7
2     6  19.7
3     8  15.1

> summarize_function(max)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl   var
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4  33.9
2     6  21.4
3     8  19.2
```